# Opencv Create Samples .vec file was not created

Tags: c++, opencv, cascade, training-data, cascade-classifier

I'm trying to make a `.vec` file for using to create my cascade training XML file. While trying to run the code, I see an error and I couldn't find any answer about this.

May you help me, please?

The error is like that:

> Unable to open image: pozitif1.jpg OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -9
>   () in cvSetImageROI, file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp,
>   line 3021

Comment: Posting is tagged with c# yet file name is cpp (c++).

Comment: excuse me i wrote wrong